# Verify Signature with PEM Public Key

Tags: apex, crypto

In Apex, how do I implement the webhook verification from Ironclad described [here](https://developer.ironcladapp.com/docs/webhook-verification)?

Their example uses Node.js and basically boils down to this:

```js
const isValid = crypto
  .createVerify(signAlgorithm)

  // The data to be verified is a concatenation of eventId, nonce, and the request body
  .update(eventId)
  .update(JSON.stringify(body))
  .update(nonce)

  .verify(publicKey, signature, encoding);

return isValid;
```

Here is what I'm running in anonymous apex attempting to replicate the above:

```
String publicKey = //'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----' + // encoded in PEM format
'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' +
'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' +
'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' +
'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // + '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
String eventId = 'webhookEventxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
String encoding = 'base64';
String signAlgorithm = 'RSA-SHA256'; // Ironclad returns sha256
String nonce = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
String signature = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=';
String body = '{' +
  '"companyID": "605b9829cdd37d296123f4b4",' +
  '"payload": {' +
    '"event": "workflow_launched",' +
    '"templateID": "6063ac9e01a5542dafa3722b",' +
    '"workflowID": "611fbd699f4a33b41d9f8295"' +
  '},' +
  '"webhookID": "611fb96cb670f852d58db210"' +
'}';

Boolean verified = Crypto.verify(
  signAlgorithm,
  Blob.valueOf(eventId + nonce + body),
  Blob.valueOf(signature),
  EncodingUtil.base64Decode(publicKey)
);

System.assert(verified);
```

I recognize that there are multiple areas where this test sample could be failing, including the formatting of the JSON body. But is the set up of the [`Crypto.verify()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#apex_System_Crypto_verify) method correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crypto.verify(..) - format of a public key](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/281029/crypto-verify-format-of-a-public-key)

Comment: @identigral No, it doesn't, but thank you. I did reference that answer when commenting out the BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY in my `publicKey` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The Ironclad documentation reads

   > The data that will need to be verified is a concatenation of the `eventId` and `nonce` properties, and the request body (as a JSON string)...

   listing `nonce` before `body`, but their Node example shows `nonce` as the final item. So really, should be using `Blob.valueOf(eventId + body + nonce)`.
2. Need to decode the signature `EncodingUtil.base64Decode(signature)`

```
Boolean verified = Crypto.verify(
  signAlgorithm,
  Blob.valueOf(eventId + body + nonce),
  EncodingUtil.base64Decode(signature),
  EncodingUtil.base64Decode(publicKey)
);
System.assert(verified);
```

Comment: Thx for reporting back.